# Android: Random crash issue

Tags: android, crash

I am getting a random crash but I am not able to figure out where exactly in the code it is happening. 
The app suddenly exits randomly.
This comes around the time when when I am trying to populate a list using ListUI. But not sure of the reason.
The relevent stack trace is mentioned below. Could someone please give me direction, as to what kind of problem could be leading to this issue.

```
W/InputDispatcher(  188): channel '4171e5b0 com.pv.example.impl/com.pv.example.impl.ExampleActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(  188): channel '4171e5b0 com.pv.example.impl/com.pv.example.impl.ExampleActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher(  188): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4171e5b0 com.pv.example.impl/com.pv.example.impl.ExampleActivity (server)'
I/ActivityManager(  188): Process com.pv.example.impl (pid 2419) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  188): Force removing ActivityRecord{41748ee8 com.pv.example.impl/.ExampleActivity}: app died, no saved state
I/WindowManager(  188): WIN DEATH: Window{4171e5b0 com.pv.example.impl/com.pv.example.impl.ExampleActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(  188): WINDOW DIED Window{4171e5b0 com.pv.example.impl/com.pv.example.impl.ExampleActivity paused=false}
D/Zygote  (  120): Process 2419 terminated by signal (11)
W/InputManagerService(  188): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2419 uid 10058
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6082K, 45% free 19093K/34631K, paused 26ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_CONCURRENT freed 135K, 40% free 20995K/34631K, paused 3ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1905K, 41% free 20712K/34631K, paused 26ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1734K, 40% free 20860K/34631K, paused 23ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1220K, 38% free 21663K/34631K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2541K, 39% free 21156K/34631K, paused 2ms+10ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 39% free 21156K/34631K, paused 21ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1440): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.673MB for 3097616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 31% free 24178K/34631K, paused 53ms
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3784K, 39% free 21247K/34631K, paused 20ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1440): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.427MB for 2747152-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1440): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 31% free 23929K/34631K, paused 2ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm(  188): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1399K, 15% free 17287K/20231K, paused 10ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm( 2234): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 5% free 12905K/13447K, paused 3ms+4ms
```

Comment: What your code is exactly for?

Comment: post the relevant part of the code

Comment: In the code we try to populate a list of items using listUI. I am not sure where exactly the issue points to, so could you please give me some hint when this kind of issue comes and i shall give more details about the code/paste it here

Comment: As i have no idea which part of the code or which class is leading to this.

Comment: as per your log cat it seems you are using broadcast receiver.. and you are trying to unregister it.. you should check the null condition or alive condition before unregister ..

Comment: have a look on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682043/how-to-check-if-receiver-is-registered-in-android

Comment: @ itsrajesh4uguys: thanks, i am looking at that. but I was also able to reproduce this scenario again and it did not have this trace. But "Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2419 uid 10058" is there. What does  that trace mean?