# How to check if a receiver is registered or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an issue about `unregisterReceiver` function. In my service, I have a function to register a `mGattUpdateReceiver` as follows

```
if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
  Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
  bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
}
```

And I release it in `onDestroy` function

```
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mGattUpdateReceiver != null) {
       unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    }
    if (mServiceConnection != null) {
       unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }
}
```

The above process worked well when my bluetooth is turn on. However, if the bluetooth is turn off, the register function does not pass. Hence, I got the error as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered
```

Hence, I need to know the receiver (`mGattUpdateReceiver`) is registered or not. How to check it in Android? Thank all

Comment: This question was already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682043/how-to-check-if-receiver-is-registered-in-android)

Comment: Do you tried it? I tried these method but it does not work. Could you recommend to me which one is good

Comment: well a solution that I found in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329949/check-if-the-broadcstreceiver-is-registered , is to put your code of onDestroy() method inside a try/catch block.

Comment: @user8430 it is better to register receiver anyways, if bluetooth is not enabled you simply will not receive callback, otherwise add flag if it regestered or not

Comment: Flag is not good solution. I think about this before. @VivekMishra: Thanks. The try catch is work. Do you have any other better solution? Because try catch as `try  {
                unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` print the log error

Comment: you usually don't have to do anything if it enters catch block. For another solution you can force user to turn on bluetooth if that is really important for your app.