# How could I check if my root broadcast receiver is enabled?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a boot receiver working perfectly in my app.

Now, I need to know if my receiver is *enabled* on the system, because some UI systems like MIUI (EMUI, etc.) let change this kind of permissions to the user...

[image: Enable start applications from boot]

I have been reading about that on this post [How to check if Receiver is registered in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682043/how-to-check-if-receiver-is-registered-in-android) But best answers came from 2010! (pre Gingerbread).

The most common response is: there is no way, you can just call `unregisterReceiver` and swallow the exception...

But sincerely.. I don't understand the logic behind that or how I can take advantage of this workaround.

- Is there a new way to check broadcast receivers?
- If not, How can I use `unregisterReceiver` safely? (I don't really want to *unregister* my receiver)

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a receiver registered in the Manifest or registered in the Activity?

Comment: Registered in the Manifest, why?

Comment: Because you don't have a reference to the receiver from the Manifest (The system creates it) so you couldn't use `unregisterReceiver` anyway.

Comment: I'm worried that none of those things would work anyway because this is a custom feature of MIUI.  Their way of doing it may be to keep your `BroadcastReceiver` registered, but simply not send the broadcast to it when the time comes.

Comment: In this case, there isn't any solution.. thx @DeeV